# PHP built-in webserver does not serve any assets

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, webserver, php-7.2

I am developing a small web app using Laravel 5.6.
I recently upgraded Laravel to 5.6 and therefore also updated PHP to version 7.2.3 as php7.1 is a requirement for Laravel.

I am developing on a Windows 10 machine.

For testing I am using the php built-in webserver.
I either use the Laravel shortcut to start the server `php artisan serve` or I call directly the `php -S localhost:8000 -t public` command, the result is the same.

Since I updated php, I am not able to access any asset (css, js) through the browser.

blade file:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Site</title>
    <link href="{{ asset('css/search.css') }}" rel='stylesheet'>
</head>
```

Output in Chrome:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Site</title>
    <link href="http://localhost:8000/css/search.css" rel='stylesheet'>
</head>
```

Folder structure of the laravel project is:

```
- Root of Laravel Project
    - public
        - css
            - search.css
```

I can't access the `search.css` file by entering `http://localhost:8000/css/search.css`, the server logs `127.0.0.1:52980 [404]: /css/search.css - No such file or directory`

The file is in the right place, and the generated urls are also correct. In fact I didn't change anything and with older php version it worked. But of coursed I double checked a dozent times.
Validating the path in my `controller.php` with a few lines of code:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $t3 = public_path("css\\search.css");
    var_dump($t3);
    var_dump(file_exists($t3));
}
```

And the result was:
`string(91) "C:\Users\me\Documents\LaravelProject\public\css\search.css" bool(true)`

Deploying the application to a AWS EB environment will work.
So my guess, that there is a problem with the built-in webserver.

Can anybody imagine, what is wrong?
The small webserver is of course very handy during development.

Comment: check the file permission.

Comment: I checked the file permission. System, my user and Administrator have full access (I am also admin on this system). I also tried adding Everybody as user and give full permission. Still the same problem ... May I have set the permission not correct?

Comment: when you try to access the url `http://localhost:8000/css/search.css` what error/response do you get in your console/network tab.

Comment: The browser brings http404 error page, saying `Not found: The requested resource /css/search.css was not found on this server.` In the console where I started the server the following message appears `[Sat Mar 24 19:24:04 2018] 127.0.0.1:59448 [404]: /css/search.css - No such file or directory`. And the chrome dev tools reports `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: test these - place any random file in the directory and try to access it? also move files to some other directory or sub directory and try to access it.

Comment: I created a `text.txt` file in the public folder. I was not able to access it. Same http 404 messages as before. Then, I moved into `css` folder - again not accessible. Even creating a new folder `test` and putting the `text.txt` in it does not help. Always getting http 404

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167478/discussion-between-ab-in-and-caldicot).